# Proving this summation equal to a Big -$O$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Consider the following question asked in my analysis quiz.

> Consider $O(\log n)$, where $n = x/2,\dots,x/2^A$, where $A= [\log x /\log 2] , [ \cdot]$ is greatest integer function, then prove that summing $O(\log n)$ at $n= x/2,\dots, x/2^A$ equals $O((\log x)^2) $.

*Attempt:* I proved it equal to $O(\log (x/2)) + O(\log(x/4)) +\dots+O(\log(x/2^A) $ =$ O(\log x^A)= O(\log(x))$,

which is not equal to what is to be proved. So, can you please guide me how to prove it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "summing $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$.." The symbol $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ is used to describe a class of function.

Comment: After last equality one extra and one missing bracket - typo?

Comment: and $A$ is not constant, you cannot hide it in big-$O$, it's "almost" $\log x$, so ?

Comment: @Anurag A. Sum of sets of functions are defined algebraically.

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\left[ {\log x/\log 2} \right]} {\log \left( {\frac{x}{{2^k }}} \right)}  \le \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\left[ {\log x/\log 2} \right]} {\log x}  = \left[ {\log x/\log 2} \right]\log x = \mathcal{O}((\log x)^2 )
$$